# LINQ query recoge los valores en objeto keyValuePair pero luego no puedo guardarlos todos en la lista

Tags: lista, linq, select

El siguiente query LINQ coge todos los parámetros y todas las estaciones y los usa para crear una cadena y también los guarda en una lista de pares de claves/valor  idestacion/parametro. Para evitar confusiones he de aclarar que esta fila:

```
  from x in selection.parameters
```

representa x estaciones , y cada una tiene x parameters

el primer select coge bien las X estaciones (selection.parameters) y sus X parametros (x.parameters) en 'Result'

pero en el segundo select anidado en 'Values' solo coge los parámetros de la primera estación:

```
    var selectionData = from x in selection.Parameters
                        select new
                        {
                            Result = "(p.col_IdEstacion = " + x.Station + " 
                            and p.col_Sigla in(" + ("'" + string.Join("','", x.Parameters) + "'") +  "))",
                            Values = (from y in x.Parameters
                            select new KeyValuePair<string, string> 
                            (x.Station.ToString(), y)).ToList()
                        };
```

la razon por la que creo Values es para coger tambien todos los pares de estaciones,parametro y meterlos en una lista con addRange , queria coger todos los pares con LINQ

```
  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>  myList
```

**ACTUALIZADO**: el LINQ esta cogiendo los valores, pero los estoy insertando mal en la lista:

```
  valores.AddRange(selectionData.Select(d => d.Values).FirstOrDefault());
```

debe ser la función FirstOrDefault() que solo coge una estación, como podría añadirlas todas?

**RESPUESTA**: valores.AddRange(selectionData.**SelectMany**(d => d.Values)) , Gracias Alberto era justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código funciona correctamente.

```
public class Estacion
{
    public string Station { get; set; }
    public List<string> Parameters { get; set; }
}

public static class Selection
{
    public static List<Estacion> Parameters { get; set; } = new List<Estacion>();
}
```

He supuesto que estas pueden ser tus clases (Lo ideal seria que las publicaras)

```
        Selection.Parameters.Add(new Estacion()
        {
            Station = "s1",
            Parameters = new List<string>()
            {
                "p1","p2","p3"
            }
        });

        Selection.Parameters.Add(new Estacion()
        {
            Station = "s2",
            Parameters = new List<string>()
            {
                "a1","a2","a3"
            }
        });

        var selectionData = from x in Selection.Parameters
                            select new
                            {
                                Result = "(p.col_IdEstacion = " + x.Station + " and p.col_Sigla in(" + ("'" + string.Join("','", x.Parameters) + "'") + "))",
                                Values = (from y in x.Parameters
                                          select new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                                          (x.Station.ToString(), y)).ToList()
                            };
```

Y el objeto que obtengo es:

```
[
{
    "Result": "(p.col_IdEstacion = s1 and p.col_Sigla in('p1','p2','p3'))",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Key": "s1",
            "Value": "p1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "s1",
            "Value": "p2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "s1",
            "Value": "p3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Result": "(p.col_IdEstacion = s2 and p.col_Sigla in('a1','a2','a3'))",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Key": "s2",
            "Value": "a1"
        },
        {
            "Key": "s2",
            "Value": "a2"
        },
        {
            "Key": "s2",
            "Value": "a3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Dime cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener y te echo una mano.

Comment: .... me acabo de dar cuenta con tus objetos que puede que este bien , lo que hago mal es lo siguiente , hago un  valores.AddRange(selectionData.Select(d => d.Values).FirstOrDefault());  y solo coge s1, no s2, como podria añadirlos  todos de vez ?

Comment: valores.AddRange(selectionData.SelectMany(d => d.Values))). El select many coge todas las lista Values y las une

Comment: Perfecto Alberto era justo lo que estaba buscando, Gracias!